# UnboundLocalError for returned variables in Python

Tags: python

I have the following Python 2.7 code (just an example as the actual code is much larger).

```
def test_function():
    ...
    x, y, z = parse_xml(filepath)
    test_dict[key].append([a, x, y, z, b])
    ...

def parse_xml(filepath):
    ...
    x = node.text  # Parse an XML file and set x to be the value of one of the nodes
    ...
    return x, y, z
```

The script was running for hours before it terminated with the error

```
File "test.py", line 660, in parse_xml 
  return x, y, z
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

I'm not sure what caused the error, because my `x` variable is always a local variable. Do I need to put `parse_xml` before `test_function`?

Comment: When you talk about reordering `parse_xml` and `test_function` that makes me suspect something is missing from the code in the question. As they stand they both appear to have their own local variable `x` which has been assigned. Are there some `if`s in `parse_xml` which give a way for `x` to be uinbound at the `return`?

Comment: There is an `if` statement that determines if `x` is assigned a value. I will do a `try/except` in `test_function()` to catch the case when `x` isn't assigned a value.

Comment: There's not enough code shown to tell where the problem is - it's probably in `parse_xml`